# An infinite version of the Dilworth theorem

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics

The Dilworth theorem for finite posets implies that a finite poset contains either a "large" chain or a "large" antichain. I am sure I saw an infinite version of this :

An infinite poset has either an infinite chain or an infinite antichain.

But I can't find a reference to that statement. What is the reference or a proof?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is studied in Reverse Mathematics as the [Chain Antichain Principle](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e849/71951a12a859da7d7f46acc78b5374aef557.pdf) (CAC)
and it is observed that it follows from Ramsey's theorem.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer led me to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96436/prove-that-for-any-infinite-poset-there-is-an-infinite-subset-which-is-either-li where Robert Israel gAve a very easy proof of the claim.

Answer (score 5):

There is an exercise in Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics (Ex. 12 in Chapter 3 of Vol. 1): "True or false: if every chain and every antichain of a poset $P$ is finite, then $P$ is finite." It also contains a direct proof in the Solutions section, not using Ramsey theorem.

Comment: I should mention that in Reverse Mathematics, the form of Ramsey's theorem that is needed here is quite weak -- weaker than the statement that for each $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$, range($f$) exists as a set.

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen well, probably this is not logical, but methodological difference

Comment: Yes..  and nice that Stanley is available free online

Comment: Stanley himself is on MO sometimes.